# About GitLab's Ldap synchronization

Tags: ldap, gitlab-ce

I'm using Docker's GitLab CE and Docker's Ldap (389ds).
I want these to be LDAP synchronized.
Currently, users created in LDAP can log in with GitLab.
However, users created in GitLab are not reflected in LDAP.
Are these correct?

I watched it for a day. no change.

Edited gitlab.rb.
`gitlab_rails['ldap_sync_worker_cron'] = "*/3 * * * *"`

no change.